# Any Python modules out there that do anything with HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGAUGE?

Tags: python, http, http-headers, http-accept-language

I have read that decoding the potentially long string which can be returned from a website for HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE is not necessarily straightforward.  Are there any packages out there in Python that try to do anything with this.  I, in particular, am interested in getting at least the list of languages that are acceptable, if not getting them in their proper requested ordering.  Ideally, if the full definition (which can be seen at http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.4) were implemented that would be the best case in case my requirements change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some time ago I took [this snippet](https://gist.github.com/1106488) from [tweetengine](http://github.com/Arachnid/tweetengine/) 
It's worked well for me. Hope it helps.

Comment: Sweet.  I'll check it out later today and get back to you